# At what point in time does Unity-Container dispose it's object in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

I am write a WPF app using c# with the help of Prism 6 Library using the known MVVM design pattern.

I am using Unity-Container to inject dependencies into my objects and trying to understand at what point in time these objects are disposed.

When the app first starts, I register my dependencies like, a unit-of-work, a db-context and other dependencies.

The thing that is puzzling me is at what point in time does these objects get disposed.

I tied to put a break point on the `Dispose()` method in a class that implements the `IDisposable` interface, but it never seems to get calls. My app, will close and the break point never get called.

My application could be closed using the "X" icon on the upper right hand side, explicitly using the `System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();` the Windows restart/shutdown, or using the task manager to force the task to end.

At what point does Unity dispose the registered dependencies?

Also, when I am using DbContext class with Entity Framework, at what point it time is the connection to the database is open and when does it get closed? Am I supposed to register my DbConntection and the UnitOfWork class as singleton or some other LifeTimeManager?

Comment: Unity calls `Dispose` on all `IDisposable` created through unity when you call `Dispose` on the container. As for `DbContext`, it is also `IDisposable` so you need to dispose it. Treat it like a blackbox and do not concern yourself with the connections. There is a ridiculous article that says `DbContext` does not need to be disposed but do not listen to that article. The article basically points out that the way it is implemented, it does not need disposing. What the author fails to realize is that implementation can change anytime.

Comment: btw, implementing `IDisposable` doesn't mean that `Dispose` _must_ be called, but rather that you have the _option_ to clean up at a defined point in time. You will never leak any managed resources because the GC takes care of that, and any type actually directly owning unmanaged resources must have a finalizer to release them eventually. That acts completely independent of `Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

> At what point does Unity dispose the registred dependencies?

When you dispose the container, that is, *never*. And then only types registered with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` (or `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`).

Unity is there to create stuff for you, it's up to you what you do with it and when you destroy it.

> at what point it time is the connection to the database is open and when does it get closed?

Instances are created when needed, that is, when you resolve them directly or resolve a type that needs them as dependency or dependency of a dependency...

Comment: Well, how do I go about disposing the objects in my container properly? I mean at what point would I then call the `Container.Dispose()` and is that enough to dispose the resolved items?

Comment: *Unity is there to create stuff for you, it's up to you what you do with it and when you destroy it.* This is totally incorrect. Whoever creates, has to destroy. If unity is creating, unity has to destroy. If unity fails to do so is another issue. The statement about EF connections is not correct either.

Comment: There's no statement about EF connections in my answer. I'm generally talking about when instances are created by Unity. Creating, for example, an unit of work, does not mean, that I'm also opening a connection.

Comment: Also, _Whoever creates, has to destroy_ is dubious, to say the least. Think about the abstract factory. It's all about creating stuff, handing it  over to whomever wanted it created, and that one is responsible (and/or allowed) to destroy it.

Comment: @Mike: you don't. Singletons will live until your process dies, you should not dispose them, because Unity will happily inject the disposed instances the next time they are resolved. Transient items must be disposed of by their respective owners, i.e. those they are injected into or whoe created them (through a factory that itself has been injected)

Comment: Have you used unity through config files? There is no way you can get your hands on the created objects so how will you dispose them?

Comment: If you don't get the created objects, then what's the use creating them?